# How to run the Google Speed Tracer in code (Java, etc)

Tags: performance, speedtracer

I want to log some front-end logs including paint issues, DOM changes AJAX calling in chrome/firefox. How to start and control the Google Speed Tracer via Java Code or CLI?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is using dynaTrace AJAX Edition.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? Show what it can do?